# Mystery behind death of Ahiravan and Meghnath

Tags: ramayana, history, hanuman

1.) I was watching Ramanand Sagar's Ramayana where Ravan talks about calling Ahiravan for help but doesn't do it. However, Ahiravan's death is not shown in this Ramayana. After doing some research I came to know that the reason Ahiravan's death is not shown in Ramanand Sagar's Ramayana because there is no proof given in Valmiki's Ramayana. However, this incident seems to be mentioned in different versions of Ramayana and also in Hanuman Ashtak in the following verse:

Bhandhu Samet Jabai Ahi Raavana Lai Raghunath Pataal Sidhaaro
Debihi Puji Bhali Bidhin So Bali Dewoo Sabai Mili Mantra Vichaaro
Jaaya Sahaaya Bhayo Taba Hi Ahi Raavana Sainya Samet Sanghaaro

Can anyone enlighten me on this as I am curious if this incident happened?

2.) If the above incident really happened then the other thing which confuses me is that Ahiravan took Ram and Laxman to Patal Lok when they were sleeping in their tent and Hanuman was guarding outside. However, so many resources online mention that Laxman didn't sleep for 14 years and as per the Meghnath's boon as he can only be killed by someone who hasn't slept or eaten in 14 years.

Please enlighten me on this incident as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who were Ahiravan and Mahiravan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/who-were-ahiravan-and-mahiravan)

Comment: I am actually aware of this story but my doubt was different. However, thanks for trying to help me! :)

Comment: part 1) of your question is answered in the [Who were Ahiravan and Mahiravan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/who-were-ahiravan-and-mahiravan) , while your 2) is answered in this - [Did Urmila Really Sleep for Fourteen Years?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23801/did-urmila-really-sleep-for-fourteen-years/23804#23804). Since there's no basis for Lakshman not sleeping for 14 years, part (2) of your question is voided. As such your question is a duplicate of two different question.

Comment: 1.) After reading the first part answer carefully I understood that the incident of Ahiravan did happen. However, that still didn't fully answer my question. After doing more research online I understood that the incident of Ahiravan death was not mentioned in Valmiki Ramayan but Tulsidas did mention it and also Hanuman Ashtak.

Comment: 2.) The second part link you provided states that Laxman did not sleep for 14 years and Urmilla slept for his part as well. However, it still didn't answer my question which was about Laxman not sleeping for 14 years but slept when Ahiravan took Ram and Laxman. I did manage to find some sources where it's mentioned that Ahiravan might have made them unconscious or it was part of Lord Ram's Leela which makes sense. Hence, none of my questions were duplicate. Anyways, thanks again for your help! :-)

Comment: Did you even read the linked questions properly? I guess, No. Both stories - *Lakshmana NOT sleeping for  14 years and/or Urmila sleeping for 14 years on her husband's behalf* - these are only folklore tales from local places, not canonical. Thus, your question doesn't hold ground since noone slept or kept themselves awake for 14 years. Lakshman like a normal human being slept, ate and walked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Urmila Really Sleep for Fourteen Years?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23801/did-urmila-really-sleep-for-fourteen-years)